# Server-side file system browser

Tags: node.js, express, server, filesystems

I am creating a node.js web interface for an internal project in the company I am working at. The web page should allow users to select a file that is in the server memory disk for processing. I want to do something like a file browser but for the server-side file system.

I tried implementing it with `jqueryfiletree` but was not successful since I can not seem to put it to work. Is there any cheap trick or an useful package to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `node.js` you can get all files names in folder, using the fuction `fs.readdir()`. After that you can read file by name `fs.readfile()` and send him on client by http.

I think this is simplest solution.